# How to calculate the sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

**Quick question** : How could i change the WHERE clause in order to have all those metrics and then compare it > 0

instead of having to make
 (d.metric1 > 0 **or** d.metric2 > 0 **or** d.metric3 > 0 **or** d.metric4 > 0 **or** d.metric5 > 0)

```
SELECT  a.No as NoRB, 
    a.Account# as Account#RB,
    b.Account# as Account#2,
    b.No as No2,
    b.type_cd as type_cd2,
    b.EffectiveDate as EffectiveDate2,       
    b.ExpirationDate as ExpirationDate2,
    b.EntranceDate as EntranceDate2,
    c.postalCode as postal_code2,
    d.No, 
    d.ExpirationDate, 
    d.EntranceDate, 
    d.metric1, 
    d.metric2, 
    d.metric3, 
    d.metric4, 
    d.metric5, 
    d.metric6, 
    d.metric7, 
    d.metric8, 
    d.metric9, 
    d.metric10, 
    d.metric11
FROM DB.CarInsurance a INNER JOIN
     DB.CarInsurance b
     ON a.No = b.No INNER JOIN 
     2ndDB.CarInsuranceINT c
     ON a.Account# = c.Account# INNER JOIN
     2ndDB.CarDriver d 
     ON a.No = d.No
WHERE a.type_cd in ('OcPr','OcNotPr') and
      b.type_cd = 'Pr' and
      a.DateDelivery >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00' and
      (d.metric1 > 0 or d.metric2 > 0 or d.metric3 > 0 or d.metric4 > 0 or d.metric5 > 0)
ORDER BY a.No, a.Account#, a.ExpirationDate, a.EntranceDate , a.EffectiveDate;
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Make your table aliases abbreviations for the table names rather than arbitrary letters.  (3) Explain what values the metrics might have.

Comment: Are you looking to simplify the `OR`ed conditions in the `WHERE` clause, or you want to change it so it produces a different resultset?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your DBMS supports this Standard SQL syntax:

```
AND 0 < ANY (d.metric1, d.metric2, d.metric3, d.metric4, d.metric5)
```

or supports GREATEST:

```
AND GREATEST(d.metric1, d.metric2, d.metric3, d.metric4, d.metric5) > 0
```

Edit:

As Gordon mentioned, GREATEST/LEAST will not work correctly for NULLs (at least in the DBMSes I know), because a single NULL yields a NULL result. And fixing it using COALESCE is more complicated than the original ORed conditions.

Comment: I think `ANY` works correctly with `NULL` values.  I wouldn't recommend `GREATEST()`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the values and compare the sum

```
AND (d.metric1 + d.metric2 + d.metric3 + d.metric4 + d.metric5) > 0
```

Or if your SQL-Server supports IIF you can try to put the comparision into the select and only the result in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT IIF((d.metric1 + d.metric2 + d.metric3 + d.metric4 + d.metric5) > 0, 1, 0) as go,
...
FROM ...
WHERE go = 1 AND...
```

Or a CASE statement in SELECT like

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN (d.metric1 + d.metric2 + d.metric3 + d.metric4 + d.metric5) > 0
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
       END as go
...
FROM...
WHERE go = 1
AND...
```

Comment: This assumes that the metrics are never negative or `NULL`.  That is not specified in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well you're right. In this case ANY would be the better choice,